# Append an existing DataFrame with output from def as DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, return

I want to append an existing `DataFrame` with the output from a defined routine which returns itself a `DataFrame`. I want to take six of the thirteen columns and append the existing dataframe. Here is my code to create the output from the defined routine:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import csv
import pandas

sqrt_annual = 255**(1/2)
path = 'data_prices.csv'
data = pandas.read_csv(path, sep=';', encoding='utf-8-sig')
data['DATE'] = pandas.to_datetime(data['DATE'], format='%Y%m%d')
data = data.sort_values(by=['TICKER', 'DATE'], ascending=[True, True])

def vol(ticker, date, date_prev, date_next):
    data_filtered = data[(data.TICKER==ticker) & (data.DATE > date_prev) & (data.DATE < date_next)]

    data_filtered['pct_change'] = data_filtered.PRICE.pct_change()
    data_filtered['log_ret'] = np.log(data_filtered.PRICE) - np.log(data_filtered.PRICE.shift(1))

    data_filtered['rolling_vola_40'] = sqrt_annual * data_filtered.shift(1).log_ret.rolling(center=False,window=40).std()
    data_filtered['rolling_vola_80'] = sqrt_annual * data_filtered.shift(1).log_ret.rolling(center=False,window=80).std()

    data_filtered['f_rolling_vola_40'] = sqrt_annual * data_filtered.shift(-40).log_ret.rolling(center=False,window=40).std()
    data_filtered['f_rolling_vola_80'] = sqrt_annual * data_filtered.shift(-80).log_ret.rolling(center=False,window=80).std()


    data_filtered['rolling_vola_prev_annum'] = sqrt_annual * data_filtered[(data.DATE < date)].log_ret.std()
    data_filtered['rolling_vola_post_annum'] = sqrt_annual * data_filtered[(data.DATE > date)].log_ret.std()

    prev_x = len(data_filtered[(data_filtered.DATE <= date)])-1
    post_x = len(data_filtered[(data_filtered.DATE >= date)])-1

    if prev_x > 235 and post_x > 235:
        return(data_filtered[(data_filtered.DATE == date)])
```

For example, the output for `print(vol('A UN Equity','2014-11-17','2013-11-14','2015-11-16'))` would be:

```
          DATE       TICKER  PRICE  pct_change  log_ret  rolling_vola_40  \
279 2014-11-17  A UN Equity  41.24   -0.007938 -0.00797         0.253339   

     rolling_vola_80  f_rolling_vola_40  f_rolling_vola_80  \
279         0.212863           0.247969           0.241233   

     rolling_vola_prev_annum  rolling_vola_post_annum  
279                 0.217963                 0.225887
```

I then have the `DataFrame` that I want to append:

```
path_static = 'data_static.csv'
data_static = pandas.read_csv(path_static, sep=';', encoding='utf-8-sig')
data_static = data_static[(data_static.DATE_PREV != 0) & (data_static.DATE_NEXT != 0)]

data_static['DATE'] = pandas.to_datetime(data_static['DATE'], format='%Y%m%d')
data_static['DATE_PREV'] = pandas.to_datetime(data_static['DATE_PREV'], format='%Y%m%d')
data_static['DATE_NEXT'] = pandas.to_datetime(data_static['DATE_NEXT'], format='%Y%m%d')
```

I now want to take the last six columns and append my current `DataFrame`. The input for the function is the following:

```
vol(data_static['TICKER'], data_static['DATE'], data_static['DATE_PREV'], data_static['DATE_NEXT'])
```

Anyone with a hint on how I can get this done?

EDIT:
Here is some dummy data.

`data_static.csv` (including headers):

```
YEAR;DATE;TICKER;LONG_COMP_NAME;ISSUER_INDUSTRY;INDUSTRY_SECTOR;COUNTRY;ACCOUNTING_STANDARD;ACCOUNTING_STANDARD_OVERRIDE;EQY_FUND_CRNCY;INDEX;DATE_PREV;DATE_NEXT
2015;20151116;A UN Equity;Agilent Technologies Inc;Electronic Measur Instr;Industrial;US;US GAAP;MIXED;USD;S&P500;20141117;0
2014;20141117;A UN Equity;Agilent Technologies Inc;Electronic Measur Instr;Industrial;US;US GAAP;MIXED;USD;S&P500;20131114;20151116
2013;20131114;A UN Equity;Agilent Technologies Inc;Electronic Measur Instr;Industrial;US;US GAAP;MIXED;USD;S&P500;20121119;20141117
2012;20121119;A UN Equity;Agilent Technologies Inc;Electronic Measur Instr;Industrial;US;US GAAP;MIXED;USD;S&P500;20111115;20131114
2011;20111115;A UN Equity;Agilent Technologies Inc;Electronic Measur Instr;Industrial;US;US GAAP;MIXED;USD;S&P500;20101112;20121119
2010;20101112;A UN Equity;Agilent Technologies Inc;Electronic Measur Instr;Industrial;US;US GAAP;MIXED;USD;S&P500;20091113;20111115
2009;20091113;A UN Equity;Agilent Technologies Inc;Electronic Measur Instr;Industrial;US;US GAAP;MIXED;USD;S&P500;20081114;20101112
2008;20081114;A UN Equity;Agilent Technologies Inc;Electronic Measur Instr;Industrial;US;US GAAP;MIXED;USD;S&P500;20071115;20091113
2007;20071115;A UN Equity;Agilent Technologies Inc;Electronic Measur Instr;Industrial;US;US GAAP;MIXED;USD;S&P500;20061114;20081114
2006;20061114;A UN Equity;Agilent Technologies Inc;Electronic Measur Instr;Industrial;US;US GAAP;MIXED;USD;S&P500;20051114;20071115
2005;20051114;A UN Equity;Agilent Technologies Inc;Electronic Measur Instr;Industrial;US;US GAAP;MIXED;USD;S&P500;0;20061114
2015;20160111;AA UN Equity;Alcoa Inc;Metal-Aluminum;Basic Materials;US;US GAAP;MIXED;USD;S&P500;20150112;0
2014;20150112;AA UN Equity;Alcoa Inc;Metal-Aluminum;Basic Materials;US;US GAAP;MIXED;USD;S&P500;20140109;20160111
2013;20140109;AA UN Equity;Alcoa Inc;Metal-Aluminum;Basic Materials;US;US GAAP;MIXED;USD;S&P500;20130108;20150112
2012;20130108;AA UN Equity;Alcoa Inc;Metal-Aluminum;Basic Materials;US;US GAAP;MIXED;USD;S&P500;20120109;20140109
2011;20120109;AA UN Equity;Alcoa Inc;Metal-Aluminum;Basic Materials;US;US GAAP;MIXED;USD;S&P500;20110110;20130108
2010;20110110;AA UN Equity;Alcoa Inc;Metal-Aluminum;Basic Materials;US;US GAAP;MIXED;USD;S&P500;20100111;20120109
2009;20100111;AA UN Equity;Alcoa Inc;Metal-Aluminum;Basic Materials;US;US GAAP;MIXED;USD;S&P500;20090112;20110110
2008;20090112;AA UN Equity;Alcoa Inc;Metal-Aluminum;Basic Materials;US;US GAAP;MIXED;USD;S&P500;20080109;20100111
2007;20080109;AA UN Equity;Alcoa Inc;Metal-Aluminum;Basic Materials;US;US GAAP;MIXED;USD;S&P500;20070109;20090112
2006;20070109;AA UN Equity;Alcoa Inc;Metal-Aluminum;Basic Materials;US;US GAAP;MIXED;USD;S&P500;20060109;20080109
2005;20060109;AA UN Equity;Alcoa Inc;Metal-Aluminum;Basic Materials;US;US GAAP;MIXED;USD;S&P500;0;20070109
```

`data_prices.csv` (including headers, caution very long):

```
DATE;TICKER;PRICE
20151231;A UN Equity;41.81
20151230;A UN Equity;42.17
20151229;A UN Equity;42.36
20151228;A UN Equity;41.78
20151224;A UN Equity;42.14
20151223;A UN Equity;41.77
20151222;A UN Equity;41.22
20151221;A UN Equity;40.83
20151218;A UN Equity;40.1
20151217;A UN Equity;40.78
20151216;A UN Equity;41.43
20151215;A UN Equity;40.81
20151214;A UN Equity;40.25
20151211;A UN Equity;40.19
20151210;A UN Equity;41.25
20151209;A UN Equity;40.98
20151208;A UN Equity;41.17
20151207;A UN Equity;40.7
20151204;A UN Equity;41.1
20151203;A UN Equity;40.15
20151202;A UN Equity;40.42
20151201;A UN Equity;41.06
20151130;A UN Equity;41.82
20151127;A UN Equity;41.97
20151125;A UN Equity;41.34
20151124;A UN Equity;40.67
20151123;A UN Equity;40.03
20151120;A UN Equity;39.28
20151119;A UN Equity;38.5
20151118;A UN Equity;39.34
20151117;A UN Equity;38.38
20151116;A UN Equity;37.33
20151113;A UN Equity;36.77
20151112;A UN Equity;37.49
20151111;A UN Equity;37.66
20151110;A UN Equity;37.98
20151109;A UN Equity;37.92
20151106;A UN Equity;38.14
20151105;A UN Equity;38.3
20151104;A UN Equity;38.34
20151103;A UN Equity;38.27
20151102;A UN Equity;38.59
20151030;A UN Equity;37.76
20151029;A UN Equity;37.7
20151028;A UN Equity;37.52
20151027;A UN Equity;37.05
20151026;A UN Equity;36.83
20151023;A UN Equity;37.11
20151022;A UN Equity;36.09
20151021;A UN Equity;35.9
20151020;A UN Equity;36.32
20151019;A UN Equity;36.23
20151016;A UN Equity;35.78
20151015;A UN Equity;35.58
20151014;A UN Equity;35.05
20151013;A UN Equity;35.63
20151012;A UN Equity;35.99
20151009;A UN Equity;36.23
20151008;A UN Equity;36.01
20151007;A UN Equity;35.54
20151006;A UN Equity;34.9
20151005;A UN Equity;35.34
20151002;A UN Equity;34.67
20151001;A UN Equity;33.74
20150930;A UN Equity;34.33
20150929;A UN Equity;33.74
20150928;A UN Equity;33.37
20150925;A UN Equity;34.45
20150924;A UN Equity;34.55
20150923;A UN Equity;34.95
20150922;A UN Equity;35.05
20150921;A UN Equity;35.69
20150918;A UN Equity;35.74
20150917;A UN Equity;36.4
20150916;A UN Equity;36.52
20150915;A UN Equity;36.15
20150914;A UN Equity;35.55
20150911;A UN Equity;35.96
20150910;A UN Equity;35.86
20150909;A UN Equity;35.54
20150908;A UN Equity;36.21
20150904;A UN Equity;35.06
20150903;A UN Equity;35.75
20150902;A UN Equity;35.53
20150901;A UN Equity;34.75
20150831;A UN Equity;36.31
20150828;A UN Equity;36.51
20150827;A UN Equity;36.64
20150826;A UN Equity;35.62
20150825;A UN Equity;34.36
20150824;A UN Equity;34.68
20150821;A UN Equity;36.23
20150820;A UN Equity;37.51
20150819;A UN Equity;38.4
20150818;A UN Equity;39.02
20150817;A UN Equity;38.82
20150814;A UN Equity;38.65
20150813;A UN Equity;38.56
20150812;A UN Equity;38.89
20150811;A UN Equity;39.42
20150810;A UN Equity;40.47
20150807;A UN Equity;39.99
20150806;A UN Equity;40.12
20150805;A UN Equity;40.72
20150804;A UN Equity;40.62
20150803;A UN Equity;41
20150731;A UN Equity;40.95
20150730;A UN Equity;40.97
20150729;A UN Equity;40.4
20150728;A UN Equity;40.45
20150727;A UN Equity;39.61
20150724;A UN Equity;39.31
20150723;A UN Equity;40.25
20150722;A UN Equity;40.33
20150721;A UN Equity;39.57
20150720;A UN Equity;40.06
20150717;A UN Equity;39.95
20150716;A UN Equity;40.34
20150715;A UN Equity;40.13
20150714;A UN Equity;40.49
20150713;A UN Equity;39.96
20150710;A UN Equity;39.4
20150709;A UN Equity;38.92
20150708;A UN Equity;38.75
20150707;A UN Equity;39.79
20150706;A UN Equity;39.36
20150702;A UN Equity;39.58
20150701;A UN Equity;39.26
20150630;A UN Equity;38.58
20150629;A UN Equity;38.74
20150626;A UN Equity;40.02
20150625;A UN Equity;40.05
20150624;A UN Equity;40.19
20150623;A UN Equity;39.6
20150622;A UN Equity;39.81
20150619;A UN Equity;39.49
20150618;A UN Equity;39.9
20150617;A UN Equity;39.6
20150616;A UN Equity;39.79
20150615;A UN Equity;39.52
20150612;A UN Equity;39.84
20150611;A UN Equity;40.53
20150610;A UN Equity;40.52
20150609;A UN Equity;40.12
20150608;A UN Equity;39.95
20150605;A UN Equity;40.31
20150604;A UN Equity;40.54
20150603;A UN Equity;41.1
20150602;A UN Equity;41.11
20150601;A UN Equity;40.92
20150529;A UN Equity;41.19
20150528;A UN Equity;41.75
20150527;A UN Equity;42.61
20150526;A UN Equity;42.06
20150522;A UN Equity;42.5
20150521;A UN Equity;42.32
20150520;A UN Equity;42.61
20150519;A UN Equity;42.37
20150518;A UN Equity;42.63
20150515;A UN Equity;42.04
20150514;A UN Equity;42.05
20150513;A UN Equity;41.81
20150512;A UN Equity;41.91
20150511;A UN Equity;42.62
20150508;A UN Equity;42.5
20150507;A UN Equity;41.8
20150506;A UN Equity;41.59
20150505;A UN Equity;41.59
20150504;A UN Equity;41.94
20150430;A UN Equity;41.37
20150429;A UN Equity;41.96
20150428;A UN Equity;42.18
20150427;A UN Equity;41.98
20150424;A UN Equity;42.49
20150423;A UN Equity;42.62
20150422;A UN Equity;42.71
20150421;A UN Equity;42.89
20150420;A UN Equity;43.19
20150417;A UN Equity;42.98
20150416;A UN Equity;43.13
20150415;A UN Equity;43.38
20150414;A UN Equity;43.07
20150413;A UN Equity;43.04
20150410;A UN Equity;43.55
20150409;A UN Equity;42.49
20150408;A UN Equity;42.26
20150407;A UN Equity;42.44
20150402;A UN Equity;42.05
20150401;A UN Equity;41.39
20150331;A UN Equity;41.55
20150330;A UN Equity;41.72
20150327;A UN Equity;41.11
20150326;A UN Equity;40.7
20150325;A UN Equity;40.81
20150324;A UN Equity;41.09
20150323;A UN Equity;42.2
20150320;A UN Equity;42.21
20150319;A UN Equity;42.21
20150318;A UN Equity;42.12
20150317;A UN Equity;41.58
20150316;A UN Equity;41.81
20150313;A UN Equity;40.87
20150312;A UN Equity;41.1
20150311;A UN Equity;40.85
20150310;A UN Equity;40.63
20150309;A UN Equity;41.74
20150306;A UN Equity;41.53
20150305;A UN Equity;42.22
20150304;A UN Equity;42
20150303;A UN Equity;42.26
20150302;A UN Equity;42.7
20150227;A UN Equity;42.21
20150226;A UN Equity;42.36
20150225;A UN Equity;42.2
20150224;A UN Equity;42.06
20150223;A UN Equity;41.73
20150220;A UN Equity;41.95
20150219;A UN Equity;41.15
20150218;A UN Equity;41.54
20150217;A UN Equity;40.52
20150213;A UN Equity;40.15
20150212;A UN Equity;40.02
20150211;A UN Equity;39.33
20150210;A UN Equity;39.67
20150209;A UN Equity;39.04
20150206;A UN Equity;39.34
20150205;A UN Equity;39.53
20150204;A UN Equity;39.11
20150203;A UN Equity;39.62
20150202;A UN Equity;38.69
20150130;A UN Equity;37.77
20150129;A UN Equity;38.46
20150128;A UN Equity;38
20150127;A UN Equity;38.75
20150126;A UN Equity;39.15
20150123;A UN Equity;38.81
20150122;A UN Equity;39.65
20150121;A UN Equity;38.16
20150120;A UN Equity;37.93
20150116;A UN Equity;38.25
20150115;A UN Equity;38.01
20150114;A UN Equity;39.06
20150113;A UN Equity;39.55
20150112;A UN Equity;40.11
20150109;A UN Equity;40.59
20150108;A UN Equity;40.89
20150107;A UN Equity;39.7
20150106;A UN Equity;39.18
20150105;A UN Equity;39.8
20150102;A UN Equity;40.56
20141231;A UN Equity;40.94
20141230;A UN Equity;41.37
20141229;A UN Equity;41.33
20141224;A UN Equity;41.13
20141223;A UN Equity;41.37
20141222;A UN Equity;41.88
20141219;A UN Equity;41.38
20141218;A UN Equity;40.7
20141217;A UN Equity;39.76
20141216;A UN Equity;38.47
20141215;A UN Equity;38.68
20141212;A UN Equity;39.72
20141211;A UN Equity;40.62
20141210;A UN Equity;40.34
20141209;A UN Equity;41.4
20141208;A UN Equity;41.51
20141205;A UN Equity;42.3
20141204;A UN Equity;42.27
20141203;A UN Equity;42.23
20141202;A UN Equity;41.98
20141201;A UN Equity;41.59
20141128;A UN Equity;42.74
20141126;A UN Equity;42.74
20141125;A UN Equity;42.71
20141124;A UN Equity;42.25
20141121;A UN Equity;42.25
20141120;A UN Equity;41.26
20141119;A UN Equity;40.8
20141118;A UN Equity;40.8
20141117;A UN Equity;41.24
20141114;A UN Equity;41.57
20141113;A UN Equity;41.45
20141112;A UN Equity;41.45
20141111;A UN Equity;41.66
20141110;A UN Equity;41.53
20141107;A UN Equity;40.93
20141106;A UN Equity;41.37
20141105;A UN Equity;40.13
20141104;A UN Equity;40.18
20141103;A UN Equity;40.84
20141031;A UN Equity;39.53
20141030;A UN Equity;38.8435
20141029;A UN Equity;38.9722
20141028;A UN Equity;39.0866
20141027;A UN Equity;38.6075
20141024;A UN Equity;38.6504
20141023;A UN Equity;38.4073
20141022;A UN Equity;37.9354
20141021;A UN Equity;38.6147
20141020;A UN Equity;37.4348
20141017;A UN Equity;37.3776
20141016;A UN Equity;36.9771
20141015;A UN Equity;37.0343
20141014;A UN Equity;37.0343
20141013;A UN Equity;37.7494
20141010;A UN Equity;38.3573
20141009;A UN Equity;39.3512
20141008;A UN Equity;40.3738
20141007;A UN Equity;39.3298
20141006;A UN Equity;40.4525
20141003;A UN Equity;40.6956
20141002;A UN Equity;39.9233
20141001;A UN Equity;40.1879
20140930;A UN Equity;40.7456
20140929;A UN Equity;40.8672
20140926;A UN Equity;40.4024
20140925;A UN Equity;40.6813
20140924;A UN Equity;41.4464
20140923;A UN Equity;40.7456
20140922;A UN Equity;41.1532
20140919;A UN Equity;41.6538
20140918;A UN Equity;41.7611
20140917;A UN Equity;42.1115
20140916;A UN Equity;41.4107
20140915;A UN Equity;41.4178
20140912;A UN Equity;41.9041
20140911;A UN Equity;41.1818
20140910;A UN Equity;41.2534
20140909;A UN Equity;41.0817
20140908;A UN Equity;41.2248
20140905;A UN Equity;41.4178
20140904;A UN Equity;41.2534
20140903;A UN Equity;41.5179
20140902;A UN Equity;41.5251
20140829;A UN Equity;40.8744
20140828;A UN Equity;40.8672
20140827;A UN Equity;41.0317
20140826;A UN Equity;41.3678
20140825;A UN Equity;41.2891
20140822;A UN Equity;41.2176
20140821;A UN Equity;41.4679
20140820;A UN Equity;41.711
20140819;A UN Equity;41.8755
20140818;A UN Equity;41.8469
20140815;A UN Equity;41.1747
20140814;A UN Equity;39.7731
20140813;A UN Equity;39.1725
20140812;A UN Equity;38.8578
20140811;A UN Equity;39.4728
20140808;A UN Equity;39.5014
20140807;A UN Equity;39.3655
20140806;A UN Equity;39.7517
20140805;A UN Equity;39.5014
20140804;A UN Equity;40.2308
20140801;A UN Equity;40.0949
20140731;A UN Equity;40.1092
20140730;A UN Equity;40.6026
20140729;A UN Equity;40.0663
20140728;A UN Equity;40.2522
20140725;A UN Equity;40.4239
20140724;A UN Equity;40.6455
20140723;A UN Equity;41.096
20140722;A UN Equity;41.2748
20140721;A UN Equity;40.5526
20140718;A UN Equity;40.1521
20140717;A UN Equity;39.437
20140716;A UN Equity;40.7313
20140715;A UN Equity;40.5168
20140714;A UN Equity;40.6312
20140711;A UN Equity;40.4739
20140710;A UN Equity;40.3953
20140709;A UN Equity;40.6884
20140708;A UN Equity;40.8672
20140707;A UN Equity;41.5608
20140703;A UN Equity;41.804
20140702;A UN Equity;41.5108
20140701;A UN Equity;41.6538
20140630;A UN Equity;41.0746
20140627;A UN Equity;41.1175
20140626;A UN Equity;41.3463
20140625;A UN Equity;41.4536
20140624;A UN Equity;41.2248
20140623;A UN Equity;41.5537
20140620;A UN Equity;42.0257
20140619;A UN Equity;41.9184
20140618;A UN Equity;42.3832
20140617;A UN Equity;42.0972
20140616;A UN Equity;41.7039
20140613;A UN Equity;41.8326
20140612;A UN Equity;41.7611
20140611;A UN Equity;42.1258
20140610;A UN Equity;42.1115
20140609;A UN Equity;42.3903
20140606;A UN Equity;42.1973
20140605;A UN Equity;41.9041
20140604;A UN Equity;41.0817
20140603;A UN Equity;40.9173
20140602;A UN Equity;40.6813
20140530;A UN Equity;40.717
20140529;A UN Equity;40.7313
20140528;A UN Equity;40.8386
20140527;A UN Equity;40.2451
20140523;A UN Equity;40.1736
20140522;A UN Equity;39.7159
20140521;A UN Equity;39.3226
20140520;A UN Equity;38.8364
20140519;A UN Equity;39.3083
20140516;A UN Equity;39.3512
20140515;A UN Equity;38.9651
20140514;A UN Equity;39.9376
20140513;A UN Equity;40.6384
20140512;A UN Equity;40.338
20140509;A UN Equity;39.6087
20140508;A UN Equity;39.5443
20140507;A UN Equity;39.3512
20140506;A UN Equity;39.3369
20140505;A UN Equity;39.5658
20140502;A UN Equity;39.0008
20140430;A UN Equity;38.6433
20140429;A UN Equity;38.1141
20140428;A UN Equity;38.4216
20140425;A UN Equity;38.8936
20140424;A UN Equity;39.53
20140423;A UN Equity;39.3369
20140422;A UN Equity;39.3083
20140417;A UN Equity;39.0795
20140416;A UN Equity;38.3859
20140415;A UN Equity;37.9783
20140414;A UN Equity;37.6493
20140411;A UN Equity;37.7351
20140410;A UN Equity;38.6504
20140409;A UN Equity;39.7374
20140408;A UN Equity;39.0866
20140407;A UN Equity;38.865
20140404;A UN Equity;39.7374
20140403;A UN Equity;40.4739
20140402;A UN Equity;40.524
20140401;A UN Equity;40.3023
20140331;A UN Equity;39.9877
20140328;A UN Equity;39.1081
20140327;A UN Equity;39.1081
20140326;A UN Equity;39.4513
20140325;A UN Equity;39.4442
20140324;A UN Equity;39.5157
20140321;A UN Equity;40.1092
20140320;A UN Equity;40.5454
20140319;A UN Equity;40.4954
20140318;A UN Equity;40.6098
20140317;A UN Equity;39.9018
20140314;A UN Equity;39.6444
20140313;A UN Equity;39.9376
20140312;A UN Equity;40.8029
20140311;A UN Equity;40.6598
20140310;A UN Equity;41.5823
20140307;A UN Equity;41.7754
20140306;A UN Equity;42.0257
20140305;A UN Equity;41.332
20140304;A UN Equity;41.3177
20140303;A UN Equity;40.5526
20140228;A UN Equity;40.7099
20140227;A UN Equity;40.3023
20140226;A UN Equity;40.8315
20140225;A UN Equity;40.6813
20140224;A UN Equity;40.5812
20140221;A UN Equity;40.288
20140220;A UN Equity;40.9673
20140219;A UN Equity;40.002
20140218;A UN Equity;39.437
20140214;A UN Equity;39.5085
20140213;A UN Equity;42.9624
20140212;A UN Equity;42.8265
20140211;A UN Equity;42.7121
20140210;A UN Equity;42.1973
20140207;A UN Equity;42.4905
20140206;A UN Equity;41.6824
20140205;A UN Equity;41.0674
20140204;A UN Equity;41.3392
20140203;A UN Equity;40.1521
20140131;A UN Equity;41.5823
20140130;A UN Equity;42.5548
20140129;A UN Equity;41.2248
20140128;A UN Equity;41.5465
20140127;A UN Equity;41.6896
20140124;A UN Equity;41.3821
20140123;A UN Equity;42.5262
20140122;A UN Equity;43.5702
20140121;A UN Equity;43.513
20140117;A UN Equity;43.4129
20140116;A UN Equity;43.2628
20140115;A UN Equity;43.1483
20140114;A UN Equity;42.8194
20140113;A UN Equity;42.1401
20140110;A UN Equity;42.1401
20140109;A UN Equity;41.7682
20140108;A UN Equity;41.7539
20140107;A UN Equity;41.0817
20140106;A UN Equity;40.5025
20140103;A UN Equity;40.7027
20140102;A UN Equity;40.195
20131231;A UN Equity;40.8958
20131230;A UN Equity;40.9888
20131227;A UN Equity;40.8815
20131224;A UN Equity;40.9244
20131223;A UN Equity;41.1461
20131220;A UN Equity;40.7313
20131219;A UN Equity;41.0317
20131218;A UN Equity;41.3964
20131217;A UN Equity;40.3094
20131216;A UN Equity;39.5014
20131213;A UN Equity;39.4442
20131212;A UN Equity;39.5157
20131211;A UN Equity;39.2154
20131210;A UN Equity;39.5729
20131209;A UN Equity;39.3727
20131206;A UN Equity;39.2082
20131205;A UN Equity;38.2571
20131204;A UN Equity;38.3144
20131203;A UN Equity;37.8495
20131202;A UN Equity;38.0498
20131129;A UN Equity;38.3072
20131127;A UN Equity;38.4788
20131126;A UN Equity;38.3644
20131125;A UN Equity;37.9783
20131122;A UN Equity;38.5074
20131121;A UN Equity;38.6862
20131120;A UN Equity;38.2786
20131119;A UN Equity;38.486
20131118;A UN Equity;38.6504
20131115;A UN Equity;39.2797
20131114;A UN Equity;36.1405
20131113;A UN Equity;36.6124
20131112;A UN Equity;36.6124
20131111;A UN Equity;36.684
20131108;A UN Equity;36.3121
20131107;A UN Equity;35.7901
20131106;A UN Equity;36.498
20131105;A UN Equity;36.6196
20131104;A UN Equity;36.6196
20131101;A UN Equity;36.5409
20131031;A UN Equity;36.2978
20131030;A UN Equity;36.5767
20131029;A UN Equity;36.97
20131028;A UN Equity;36.8198
20131025;A UN Equity;37.0916
20131024;A UN Equity;36.5552
20131023;A UN Equity;36.2191
20131022;A UN Equity;36.4837
20131021;A UN Equity;37.1774
20131018;A UN Equity;37.8924
20131017;A UN Equity;37.6493
20131016;A UN Equity;36.8699
20131015;A UN Equity;36.3836
20131014;A UN Equity;36.7269
20131011;A UN Equity;36.7984
20131010;A UN Equity;36.4623
20131009;A UN Equity;35.7186
20131008;A UN Equity;35.8473
20131007;A UN Equity;36.5624
20131004;A UN Equity;37.0272
```

Comment: I suggest reading the [docs - Merge, join, and concatenate](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#concatenating-objects), it's all you need

Comment: I get the DataFrames to merge but not the function to run before. This is my problem. I think I should use some sort of iteration but not sure if this is really necessary. I will later then use `pandas.merge(data_static, data, how='left', on=['TICKER', 'DATE'])`. This should work smoothly. But I need to define `data_output` first. Ideally this would be: `data_output = vol(data_static['TICKER'], data_static['DATE'], data_static['DATE_PREV'], data_static['DATE_NEXT'])`. But this isn't the way to go unfortunately.

Comment: You most probably can achieve the function using just sort + indexing eg. `df.ix[:6, :]`. find the common "index" between 2 dataframes which I guess will be "DATE", then just perform a merge

Comment: I'm confused. I can merge the queries but I cannot perform the calculation in between.

Comment: ok, i think i'm now confused. so you have the first dataframe you want to apply the function and generate new columns, so does your second dataframe. after that you want to merge with the results isn't it?

Comment: Yes, the first `DataFrame` has the static data that I want to enter into the function to perform a calculation. The calculation will generate a new `DataFrame` that I want to merge the first one with. I currently can't get the function calculation done. I tried to merge the `DataFrame` with the function but this does not work either.

Comment: `for index, row in data_static.iterrows():
    print(vol(row['TICKER'], row['DATE'], row['DATE_PREV'], row['DATE_NEXT']))` yields results, it iterates through the console and shows the results. I just can't get the same thing done for the `DataFrame` as a whole.

Comment: ok i understand it now. But i think you should really re-write your question to simply explain and focus on why your "function" isn't working.

Comment: for example, if you want to apply a function row-wise, you can simply do: `data_static.apply(lambda x: vol(x['TICKER'], x['DATE'], ...), axis=1)`, you don't need to iterate the whole frame.

Comment: I need to check this. The function itself does work but the merging does not work with the function. I will try to go down the apply route. 2 questions: What does lambda stand for? Do I need to create the new columns with empty values first?

Comment: This is the function I currently try, do you think this will work? It currently runs so I don't know: `data_static['Value'] = data_static.apply(lambda row: vol(row['TICKER'], row['DATE'], row['DATE_PREV'], row['DATE_NEXT']), axis=1)`

Comment: I get the following error: `ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 11 to array axis with dimension 1`

Comment: if you want, please post some dummy data and I could possibly look into that for you.

Comment: @Anzel I added some data for you to the OP.

Comment: I am working at the moment so won't be around for a while. but I am now seeing your end goal. You indeed need to create a result dataframe with the columns as what your function generated. then loop the second frame and append to the resulted one.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the solution the following way:

```
data_store = pandas.DataFrame(columns=('TICKER', 'DATE', 'rolling_vola_40', 'rolling_vola_80', 'f_rolling_vola_40', 'f_rolling_vola_80', 'rolling_vola_prev_annum', 'rolling_vola_post_annum'))

for index, row in data_static.iterrows():
    data_output = vol(row['TICKER'], row['DATE'], row['DATE_PREV'], row['DATE_NEXT'])
    if type(data_output) != type(None):
        data_store = data_store.append(data_output[['TICKER', 'DATE', 'rolling_vola_40', 'rolling_vola_80', 'f_rolling_vola_40', 'f_rolling_vola_80', 'rolling_vola_prev_annum', 'rolling_vola_post_annum']])

data_static = pandas.merge(data_static, data_store[['TICKER', 'DATE', 'rolling_vola_40', 'rolling_vola_80', 'f_rolling_vola_40', 'f_rolling_vola_80', 'rolling_vola_prev_annum', 'rolling_vola_post_annum']], how='left', on=['TICKER', 'DATE'])
data_static.to_csv('test.csv', sep=';', encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: It is not very fast, so there might be a better solution out there.